# How to resize image view according to screen resolution and size

Tags: android, android-imageview

I want to resize image view according to screen resolution and size. How to do it? I searched android development tutorials.. but it is useless.. pls help.. It's for my mini project..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to scale the image to X,Y coordinates by setting:

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

property.

Answer (score 0):

By default, `Android` maintain **multiple** folders for the images with different resolutions. Reason behind that is the resolution of the Android Device on which the application is gonna run.

- **hdpi** - maintain images for the Android Broad Screen set or Android Phones with the Higher resolution.
- **ldpi**  - for Lower images quality.
- **mdpi** - for medium images support.
- **xhdi** - images folder for devices with maximum resolution.

Android OS will select the image itself by checking the compatible device and its resolution. Hope this helps your cause.