# How can I resize the image according to screen resolution?

Tags: android

[image]

I am using an image in my application and I want it to fit correctly on all the device even they have different resolution.
Is there any way we can resize the image according to screen size?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to resize image view according to screen resolution and size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15321275/how-to-resize-image-view-according-to-screen-resolution-and-size)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, there are two alternative ways to do it;

1. In your XML;

   ```
   android:scaleType="fitXY"
   ```
2. In your Java code;

   ```
   yourImageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
   ```

Comment: Hi, when i use small image on bigger resolution devices then image become fade.and android:scaleType="fitXY" does not effect any thing..

Comment: what do you mean by fade? can you post a screenshot?